# Tessnet - Referenced in my project - application exits in Init call

Tags: c#, .net, tesseract, tessnet2

I referenced tessnet lib to my project and called following code..but it exists w/o any exception on Init call

```
var fd = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (fd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            var fileP = fd.FileName;
            var bmp = new Bitmap(fileP);
            var tessocr = new tessnet2.Tesseract();
            tessocr.Init(@"C:\Downloads\TesseractApp\TessApp\bin\Debug\", "eng", false);
            tessocr.GetThresholdedImage(bmp, Rectangle.Empty).Save("c:\\Downloads\\" + Guid.NewGuid() + ".bmp");
        }
```

get the project from here http://ge.tt/5AqxgSN/v/0?c

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter of `Init` specifies the location of language data files (.inttemp, .normproto, etc.). So be sure to copy them to the Debug folder when you build the project.

Comment: I did.... I tried copying all the files and made a dir tessdata and copied to it.. both didn't work.